cumulative sum via foreach: how to avoid xdef?
To draw 5 stacked rectangles, consider the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
This works:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\pgfmathsetmacro\y{0}
\foreach \dy in {10,20,30,20,10} {
  \xdef\ylag{\y}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{\y+\dy}
  \xdef\y{\temp}
  \path[draw=black,fill=blue!70]{(0,\ylag) rectangle (10,\y)};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
But note that now ylag is \ylag\ and y is \y\ in the entire document.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 

This is OK, but I'm sad to pollute the global namespace. (The actual picture is in a larger document.) Am I overlooking an approach that avoids this? More importantly, what is the canonical way to produce a cumulative sum (as this example effectively does)?

off-topic: don't end lines with \\  outside things like tabular and array.

Like this for example:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
\foreach \y [
    remember=\dy as \lasty (initially 0),
    evaluate=\y as \dy using \y+\lasty
] in {10,20,30,20,10} {
  \path[draw=black, fill=blue!70] (0,\lasty) rectangle +(10,\y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 



With this example in hand, I now understand the documentation of remember and evaluate. (I had tried them but failed.) Thanks!

I find the … as … using … syntax confusing, alternatively, evaluate={\dy=\y+\lasty;} works as well ({} and ; are mandatory, though).

@Qrrbrbirlbel Nice, this was new to me!
